# Why this image is not an horizontal gradient?

Tags: opengl, glsl

[image]

This question is not a problem I have but more why we get this result.
This image was generated rendering two cubes, with this shader:

*Fragment*:

```c
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ProjectionMatrix;

in FS {
    vec4 pos;
} fs;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main()
{
    out_Color.rgb = vec3(u_ProjectionMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * fs.pos).xxx;
}
```

*Vertex*:

```c
layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_Pos;

uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_ProjectionMatrix;

out FS {
    vec4 pos;
} fs;

void main()
{
    fs.pos = u_ModelMatrix * in_Pos;
    gl_Position = u_ProjectionMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * worldPos;
}
```

My understand is that as we get the **projected** fragment coordinates by multiplying by *MVP*, we should have `vec3(u_ProjectionMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * fs.pos)` equals to the window screen in X and Y and equals to the depth in Z. So, using `xxx` as `rgb` should show an horizontal gradient where models are drawn, with full black at center of the window (as right are negative X) and full white to the right. This is globally the result, but the color does not only depend on X, as we can see that there is vertical lines in the images that have pixels of different colors. Why does it happen ?

Comment: Ok I made it to work. I just had to divide by `w`. But why?

Comment: Because a perspective projection matrix projects to clip space. But your shader assumes NDC coordinates (all axis in [-1, 1]). By dividing by w, the clip space to NDC conversion is done. *equals to the window screen in X and Y and equals to the depth in Z*: This is also not true for NDC. x,y,z are all in [-1,1].

Comment: It's also totally unclear why you are calculating the position again in the fragment shader instead of just using `gl_FragCoord`.

Comment: The context is I try to use with shadow mapping, so the problematic was a bit more complex, I tried to trim to a minimal example. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A projection matrix transforms the input into clip space. Clip space is a homogeneous space (actually projective P^3 space), and doesn't guarantee any bound on the axis. For any point visible in clip space, the x,y,z axis have to be smaller than the w-component.

If you need your points in a space where all coordinates are in [-1,1] range, you have to homogenize the clip space coordinates by dividing it by the w coordinate.

> ... we should have `vec3(u_ProjectionMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * fs.pos)` equals to the window screen in X and Y and equals to the depth in Z:

```
NDC = clipSpace.xyz / clipSpace.w;
```

This is neither for clip space nor for NDC space true, to get to screen coordinates, one has to perform the viewport transformation which basically transforms the [-1, 1] space to a [0, width] (or [0, height]) space. To do so, you'd have to perform the following calculation:

```
windowSpace = (NDC.xy + 1.0) * ([width, height] / 2.0)
```